# Cómo formatear un número de un input

Tags: html, input

Estoy intentando formatear un input numérico en HTML, pero sólo visualmente, sin que los puntos y comas que se añadan afecten al dato real si se sigue editando. He probado varias formas, pero el problema es que puedo acceder al valor del input, por ejemplo mediante CSS, pero una vez que lo modifico, si luego sigo cambiando su valor me da un número erróneo.

He estado buscando si habría alguna forma de separar en HTML lo que se muestra formateado del dato real, algo así como un pipe de Angular, pero no la he encontrado.

¿Se os ocurre cómo podría abordar este problema? Necesito que el valor de entrada del input sea numérico, porque así me va a llegar.

La solución la estoy desarrollando con Angular y Angular Material, pero pongo este prototipo en JS al no poder poner fragmentos de mi código, por ser componentes del cliente.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="caja">0</div>
    <input type="number" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

input, div {
  margin: 20px;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#caja {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 205px;
}
```

JS:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

$('input')
  .on('input', () => $('#caja').text(
    new Intl.NumberFormat().format($('input').val())
));
```

Lo que se me ocurrió es ocultar el input, envolverlo en un div y mostrar otro div hermano del input con el resultado formateado. Pero al ocultar el input ya no tiene efecto su evento de modificación, que es el que carga el contenido del div.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Puedes colocar codigo? para que asi veamos lo que ya llevas y la pregunta no sea cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si será la mejor solución pero, después de buscar en foros (que remiten al uso de una librería externa) e intentar varias cosas sin éxito, la solución que más se aproxima a lo que busco es la siguiente:

Utilizar dos inputs: uno de tipo texto, al cual se le aplicará una máscara según vayamos escribiendo, y nuestro input real que estará oculto y que tendrá el valor puramente numérico sin ningún formato.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Input Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input class="input-text" type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <input class="input-number" type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './style.css';

$('.input-text').change(function (event) {
  const numVal = $('.input-text').val().valueOf();
  $('.input-text').val(Intl.NumberFormat().format(numVal));
  $('.input-number').val(numVal);

  console.log('Valor actual del input real', $('.input-number').val());
});
```

Si a alguien se le ocurre una solución mejor, por favor, que la ponga y así aprendemos todos.

IMPORTANTE:
No repitan la solución que he propuesto, porque ya no aportará nada al problema planteado, y será ignorada sin obtener ninguna valoración positiva.